# Computing cross-correlations on a quantum computer

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-algorithms

I am trying to compute cross-correlation on a quantum computer, and I have found a research paper describing the cross-correlation algorithm.

The terms used in the algorithm are not clear, and it would be great if someone can help me with it. The algorithm has many formating and special characters that I cannot copy and paste in the browser from the PDF.

The link to access the research paper is [Cross-Correlations computation through quantum computing](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.09519). On page number  4 the cross-correlation algorithm is mentioned.

I am not able to understand that in the second step of the algorithm, what is the j^ register, and what does it consist of?

Answer (score 3):

It is referring the the "function variable" register of figure 1. It consists of $\log_2N$ qubits, all prepared in the $|0\rangle$ state.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I wonder how the 2D matrix of the images will be encoded to quantum computer? Also confused about step 3 where it states to apply QFT to the last register. What the last register is it referring to?